# How to calculate percentage growth in haskell

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

I am running into a wall when I'm trying to calculate % growth from a list of integers to a list of floats. I am new to Haskell with very little experience and not sure where or what to search for my problem thus I came here. :)

```hs
function :: [Ints] -> [Floats]
```

I have a list.

```hs
nums = [4561,3241,2345,3455,4567]
```

I need to iterate through the list and calculate the % percentage growth from nums[4] to nums[0]
and then output a list of floats. But I am not sure whether to use a map function or some other method to solve this. I need some way to retrieve two numbers from the list i.e. nums[4] and nums[3] and calculate the % growth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you need but if it's the growth from `(n-1)`th to the `n`th element you can do it like this:

```hs
growth :: [Int] -> [Float]
growths xs = 
    zipWith (\n n' -> fromIntegral (n'-n) / fromIntegral n * 100) xs (tail xs)
```

yielding

```hs
> growths [4561,3241,2345,3455,4567]
[-28.941021,-27.645788,47.334755,32.185238]

-- this one makes it a bit more obvious what is happening
> growths [1,2,3,4,5]
[100.0,50.0,33.333336,25.0]
```

I probably got the formula wrong and you want some other formula but the idea should be clear as long as you want to compare consecutive numbers.

---

The *trick* `zipWith f xs (tail xs)` is often useful to work with consecutive elements in a list. Here the first argument to `f` is the `(n-1)`th and the second is the `n`th element in the list.

---

if you need from `n` to `n-1`th (as you kind of seem to imply) just flip the arguments:

```hs
growths xs = 
    zipWith (\n' n -> fromIntegral (n'-n) / fromIntegral n * 100) xs (tail xs)

> growths [4561,3241,2345,3455,4567]
[40.72817,38.208954,-32.12735,-24.348589]


> growths [1,2,3,4,5]
[-50.0,-33.333336,-25.0,-20.0]
```

Comment: Yes if was trying to find growth, sorry If the question was worded badly. That being said the second solution you gave me is exactly what I was looking for !! Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Just be careful if you use this in a production program: `tail` throws an exception for an empty list.

Comment: @PaulJohnson while this is true (and while I indeed did not consider the empty-list case) - here Haskells laziness saves the day for me - at least right now `zipWith` is pattern matching on the first argument ;) - try it: `growths []` should happily return `[]` - and even if it would go wrong here it's an easy fix by just adding `growths[] = []` or whatever you like

Comment: @Carsten Neat! I didn't think of that.